# Reading Binary Files in C

Tags: c, file, io, binary

Suppose a binary file (that needs to be opened for reading) is written with this function prototype:

```
void writeBinaryFile ( char *fileName , char *comment , int numberOfDoubles , double *doubles , int numberOfInts , int *ints )
```

*(More details about this function can be found in the paste below)*

...

My written code only acquires the FIRST letter of the .bin file...

Here is my function:

```
void readBinaryFile(char *fileName)
{
        FILE *fp;
        char *ptr;
        double *ptr1;
        int *ptr2;
        ptr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
        ptr1=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*6);
        ptr2=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*6);

        fp=fopen ( fileName , "rb" ) ;
        fread(ptr,sizeof(char),11,fp);
        while(*ptr!='\0')
        {
            printf("%c",*ptr);
            ptr++;

        }
        fclose(fp);
}
```

What am I missing here? I need to read more than just the *first* character in the .bin file.

Help is appreciated, as always. Thanks!

In the case anyone needs the full code in an organized manner, here is the paste:

http://pastebin.com/66jZwfUD

Comment: I notice you read 11 bytes into a space allocated for 5 bytes. That certainly can't be good.

Comment: So many questions... what does the file actually contain? What does `fread()` return?  Are the characters you send to `printf()` printable? If the file is binary, is it possibly that the second byte is simply `0` so you stop trying to print characters?

Comment: (1) no API return code checks *at all*, (2) three distinct memory leaks, (3) no length-limit on the while-loop to prevent walking into unallocated heap memory. (4) reading 11 bytes into an allocation 5 bytes wide = heap corruption all-but-guaranteed. I'm sure there are others but those were all spotted in the first 60 seconds.

Comment: This is really another one of those question where the best answer you're going to get is: "Your code makes no sense. You need to learn C."

Comment: Also, you are handling a binary file as C-string in the `while` and `printf()`(Can it really be printed by `printf` with `%c`?). Binary files can have a lot of 0s, and such 0s doesn't mean end of file/string. I believe you need to write this instead of: `int n = fread(..); int i = 0; while(i < n) { /* do something .. */ i++;}`

Comment: I forgot to make that change to 11 bytes! Done. 
`fread()` is reading the first character of the .bin file, which is simply the letter "J". I've been told the .bin file contains the letter J, followed by a few spaces, then a long (and wise) quotation. The second byte cannot be a `0`.

Comment: Considering you're allocating fixed size buffers with no apparent requirement to return them, and all of them are very small in size, you may be better served to just use local arrays rather than `malloc()` (at least until you need something big *and* you get to the part in your book that talks about `free()`).

Comment: David, that made me chuckle :) I somewhat agree with you but I don't think its necessary something like that will be the best answer.

Comment: @EngGenie: Your print code only stops on a zero byte. I don't see you saying there's sure to be a zero byte in the first 11 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

```
void readBinaryFile(char *fileName)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *ptr;
    double *ptr1;
    int *ptr2;

    ptr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*5);
    ptr1=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*6);
    ptr2=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*6);
```

Don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C. It hides errors.

```
    fp=fopen ( fileName , "rb" ) ;
```

You need to check for errors here.

```
    fread(ptr,sizeof(char),11,fp);
```

You allocated 5 bytes for `ptr`, now you're reading 11. You also should check the return value of `fread`.

```
    while(*ptr!='\0')
    {
        printf("%c",*ptr);
        ptr++;

    }
```

There's nothing to prevent this loop from running off the end of the allocated space.

```
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Now, all the memory you allocated is leaked and all the data you read into it is lost since the pointers go out of scope when you return.

Comment: Casting the return from malloc only hides errors if you're not complying with C99 where all functions have to be declared before they are used.  And the error then is that you're not using C99.