# Reading and writing binary file in C

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fread, bin

Firstly, I read here:

1. [reading-binary-files-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784549/reading-binary-files-in-c)
2. [binary-file-reading-writing-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15752546/binary-file-reading-writing-in-c)

I am trying to read binary file in C. And wrote this code:

```
struct emp
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    char no[20];
    char aldigiDersKodu[20];
};
struct emp e;
***
***
***
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("student.bin","rb+");
if(fp == NULL)
{
    fp = fopen("student.bin","wb+");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File is not opening.");
        exit(1);
    }
}
***
***
***
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

another = 'y';
while(another == 'y')
{
     printf("\nOgrencinin Adi: ");
     scanf("%s",e.name);
     printf("\nOgrencinin Soyadi: ");
     scanf("%s", &e.surname);
     printf("\nOgrencinin Numarasi: ");
     scanf("%s", &e.no);

     fwrite(&e, sizeof(struct emp), 1, fp);

     printf("\nYeni Ogrenci Ekle(y/n)\n");
     fflush(stdin);
     another = getche();
}
***
***
***
```

And I am adding lesson name and lesson code(ex: Maths,M1) to student.**(SAME METHOD)**

This read to binary file code:

```
scanf("%s", no);
rewind(fp);
while(fread(no, sizeof(struct emp), 1, fp) == 1)
{
     printf("\n%s %s %s %s", &e.name, &e.surname, e.no, &e.aldigiDersKodu);
}
```

And when I read binary file, I was looking like this **in console**:

[image]

And my bin file look like this:

Aytunc  øA‘v:A‘vXÿæ¯Yalcinkaya  °@ Àþ( 1,Aytunc,Yalcinkaya,M ‘vÍE‘v°@ ”ÿ( @ Osman   øA‘v:A‘vXÿæ¯Villi kaya  °@ Àþ( 2 ( Ìÿ(  r’vô@_Ùþÿÿÿ:A‘vÍE‘v°@ ”ÿ( @

But I want to look this output in console screen:

*1 Aytunc Yalcinkaya M*

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, And your binary file is basically a text file, there is not much difference because you are only storing text. And put the `'\n'` at the end of the printed line, because it flushes `stdout`, if you put it at the beginning of the line, some text might not be printed, I see that a lot in windows programming tutorials, but it doesn't make sense most of the time.

Comment: `while(fread(no,` --> `while(fread(&e,` ?  `printf("\n%s %s %s %s", &e.name, &e.surname, e.no, &e.aldigiDersKodu);` <-- remove `&`

Comment: Do you ever close fp? Why don't you write a very simple complete test program (simplify your struct to have only one member)? That would also help yourself.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY  while(fread(no, --> while(fread(&e, ? printf("\n%s %s %s %s", &e.name, &e.surname, e.no, &e.aldigiDersKodu); <-- remove &    => explain this comment please :) which part i should remove ??

Comment: E.g `&e.name` change to `e.name`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as you save to file a structure, you can/have to read a structure.

```
while(fread(&e, sizeof(struct emp), 1, fp) == 1)
```

Secondly you have to pass a poiter to %s format then

```
printf("\n%s %s %s %s", e.name, e.surname, e.no, e.aldigiDersKodu);
```

Or at least

```
printf("\n%s %s %s %s", &e.name[0], &e.surname[0], &e.no[0], &e.aldigiDersKodu[0]);
```